# Bootstrap's tabs-left height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I use Bootstrap tabs with `tabs-left` class. However, if the content of a large enough, the border between the menu and the content does not reach the edges. What I need to do to stretch the menu? The setting of the `height:100%` doesn't help, because the menu is using the `float: left`.

Here is my example:
http://codepen.io/Just-Boris/pen/adqbr

Comment: That's quite odd and, if it's Bootstrap's default style, really rather dumb

Comment: Are you talking about the vertical border not extending past the bottom of the tab elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by removing the right-border from nav-tabs, and adding a left-border to the content.  Then you can size the tab-content with a min-height of 100%.

```
  html, body, .tabs-left { height: 100%; }

    .tabs-left .nav-tabs {
      margin-right: 0;
      border-right: 0;
    }

    .tab-content {
      min-height: 100%;
      padding-left: 20px;
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

Comment: I also get the idea. It may be worth to offer include it in Bootstrap's default style?